# Memory Organization: Where Are Classes and Methods Stored?

Tags: c++, class, heap-memory, stack-memory

I'm looking to understand the organization of memory in my programming language, which consists of four primary areas: stack, heap, code, and data. However, I'm unclear about where the programming language stores classes and their associated methods within these memory areas.

Could someone please explain which memory area typically contains the compiled code for classes and their methods? Is it the "code" memory area?
Additionally, I'd like to understand the distinction between where class definitions and instances of classes (objects) are stored in memory.
Are there any language-specific nuances or optimizations that impact how classes and methods are allocated in memory?
I'm eager to gain a better grasp of memory management for classes and methods in my programming language. Any insights or references would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is largely implementation defined in C++.

Comment: From [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list/), perhaps you're looking for "Inside the C++ Object Model" by Stanley Lippman. Although it was published nearly 30 years ago, all the concepts you list are covered by it and are relevant today.

Comment: I'm not aware of any universal law that mandates any particular place in memory for a particular kind of data or objects.

Comment: It's your language, put them wherever you want them to go.

Comment: In most compilers, symbols, including classes, structs and templates, go into dictionaries.  They are not exported (unless in debug mode).  As far as memory organization goes, you have 3 kinds of memory:  memory pre-allocated by linker or compiler; large run-time memory (often called the heap) and smaller run-time memory (a.k.a. stack).  The large area is usually used for items that have a life time after executing a function (such as linked lists).  The smaller runtime memory is often used for items that have a short lifetime, such as local variables.

Comment: I highly recommend taking advanced data structures courses, operating system courses and compiler courses.  They should answer a lot of your questions.

Comment: Does anyone we can? explication what happen when define the class in cpp in memory

Comment: @HassanLakhal There is nothing about classes that needs to be stored anywhere. They are only needed at the language level, not at runtime. (An exception are polymorphic classes for which vtables and RTTI must be stored somewhere, statically.) Member functions can be compiled in exactly the same way as free functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Code Segment: Where the compiled code for methods is stored.
- Data Segment: Where static variables and sometimes metadata are stored.
- Heap: Where objects (instances) and, in some languages like Python and Java, class metadata and methods are stored.
- Stack: Where local variables, including references to heap-allocated objects, are stored.

Nuances:

Java: Class metadata, including the bytecode for methods, is stored in a special area called the "Method Area," which is a part of the heap.

Python: Being an interpreted language, Python handles classes as first-class objects, storing both the class definition and its methods in the heap.

C++: Methods that are not virtual are usually inline-expanded, meaning they end up directly in the Code Segment. Virtual methods result in a v-table, stored in the Data Segment, with pointers to the Code Segment.

JavaScript: Due to its dynamic nature, both class definitions and methods are stored in the heap. However, most modern JavaScript engines apply various optimizations like hidden classes and inline caching.

Comment: thank you for this explication .
but in c++ when define  construct no It doesn't happen call up v-table is this correct !!

Comment: In C++, the v-table (virtual table) is used for dynamic dispatch of virtual functions. However, if a class doesn't have any virtual functions, then no v-table is generated for that class. This means that objects of such a class won't have a v-pointer pointing to a v-table.

Comment: thank you for this explication  i understand now

Comment: Did when not exist polymorphic classes member function stored as free function